# AJAX Passing multiple parameter to WebApi

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-web-api

AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'Post',
            data: {token:"4", feed:{"id":0,"message":"Hello World","userId":4} }
        });
```

Server Side Web API:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage Post(string token, Feed feed)
 {
    /* Some code */

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
 }
```

> Error Code 404: {"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches
>   the request URI 'localhost:8080/api/feed'.","messageDetail":"No action
>   was found on the controller 'Feed' that matches the request."}

Why I am getting this error and Why I am not able POST multiple parameters to my API?

Comment: The parameter names have to match the server routing/mappings. The first parameter typically is `id` (not token) unless you changed the routing/mapping defaults.

Comment: Is this the correct code? It says you're calling `feed`, but the method name is `post`?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie **localhost:8080/api/feed**

Comment: @christiandev: feed is the controller name, not the method in a WEBAPI call like that.

Comment: Yes Feed is a controller and Post is default action for my webapi

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I wasn't sure what the controller was - but, to call the controller, it would need `feed/` with the forward slash?

Comment: @christiandev: No. It will call default defined method if it is missing the method and id parts. It does not need a trailing slash.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie this is not the case with me.
I did change my routing  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"

Answer (score 13):

Start by writing a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public Feed Feed { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action will take as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyViewModel model)
{
    /* Some code */

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

and finally adapt your jQuery call to send it as JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        token: '4',
        feed: {
            id: 0,
            message: 'Hello World',
            userId: 4
        } 
    })
});
```

Important things to note for the AJAX call:

- setting the request `contentType` to `application/json`
- wrapping the data in a `JSON.stringify` function to effectively convert the javascript object to a JSON string
- removed the useless `dataType: 'json'` parameter. jQuery will automatically use the `Content-Type` response header sent by the server to deduce how to parse the result passed to the `success` callback.

Comment: No, that's absolutely untrue. The Newtonsoft JSON serializer used by the Web API will perfectly fine handle this case. This allows for writing semantically correct variable names depending on the language: in JS variable names start with lowercase and in C#, property names start with uppercase.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov You mean I can't use multiple parameter in POST API?

Comment: You can, but the model binder will make your life much harder. It's a hell of a mess. Read here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx Once you've read this article you will absolutely forget about passing multiple parameters and simply do it the right way as shown in my answer - by using view models. This way you don't have to worry about which parameter is bound from which body or head or whatever. You have only one parameter which is your view model and the client directly sends it as JSON string in the request payload.

Comment: I agree with @DarinDimitrov (tough to disagree with someone with 464k points :) ) approach to use a viewmodel, this definitely makes things a lot cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Try this server-side (from memory you can only have a single FromBody parameter so it needs to contain all the incoming properties):

```
public class TokenAndFeed
{
    public String token {get; set;}
    public Feed feed {get; set;}
}

 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]TokenAndFeed tokenAndFeed)
 {
    /* Some code */

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
 }
```

Comment: @Mohsin JK: My bad... I think you can only have a single [FromBody] parameter, so it must contain both your objects.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem recently and here's some info on how I solved it. I think the problem is to do with how WebApi handles parameters. You can read a bit about it [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx) but essentially there are two ways to post parameters, in the body or in the uri. The body can only contain one parameter, but it can be a complex parameter, whereas the uri can contain any number of parameters (up to the uri character limit) but they must be simple. When jquery does a POST ajax call it tries to pass all data parameters in the body, which does not work in your case since the body can only have one parameter.

In code terms I think you need something like this:

```
var token = "4";
var feed = {Id:0, Message:"Hello World", UserId:4};

$.ajax({
    url: "/api/Feed/?token=" + token,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'Post',
    data: JSON.stringify(feed)
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your `Feed` class, just to make sure the properies match up.

```
var data = {
     token: "4",
     feed: {Id:0,Message:"Hello World",UserId:4}
}

$.ajax({
            url: "/api/Feed/",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'Post',
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, updated - I thought it was feed because the `/` was missing.

Comment: Here is my Feed Class,
public class Feed
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }

Comment: The properties don't match, they're case sensitive. I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one. You have to get json object data from body. Read Request's input streem and map it to your data model.

```
public class TokenAndFeed
{
public string Token { get; set; }
public Feed Feed { get; set; }
}      

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    System.IO.Stream str;
    String jsonContents;
    Int32 strLen, strRead;
    str = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
    strLen = Convert.ToInt32(str.Length);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[strLen];
    strRead = str.Read(byteArray, 0, strLen);
    jsonContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);

    TokenAndFeed tAndf = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenAndFeed>(jsonContents);

    // some code here  
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
```

hope this will help.