# Passing multiple parameters to my 'POST' ajax call to my webAPI controller > http 404 not found

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I can successfully do an ajax call to my webAPI like this:

Javascript:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "api/Breeze/DeleteMaterials",
        cache: false,
        data: { aa: 'aa', bb: 'bb' },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        traditional: true,
        success: () => { result.resolve(true); },
        error: (error) => result.reject(error)
    });
```

Web API:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public void DeleteMaterials(string aa, string bb)
    {
        // doing something here
    }
```

It works pretty well. The webAPI is reached and the value parameters are present. Now I don't want to keep a 'GET' call because here I'm performing a delete server side, I need wether a **'DELETE' or 'POST'**.

I know the 'DELETE' call is not possible because it only accepts 1 parameter and for my case I need to pass 2 parameters.

So I try to replace 'GET' by 'POST' in my previous code and the webAPI is never reached and I get the HTTP error 404: not found.

I already searched a lot in all SO suggestions but none of them gives me what I need.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok I finally got it working by the help of this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946008/ajax-passing-multiple-parameter-to-webapi the solution was (1) to use JSON.stringify and (2) to use a viewModel server side!! Many thanks Darin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javascript

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "api/Breeze/DeleteMaterials",
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({ aa: 'aa', bb: 'bb' }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    traditional: true,
    success: () => { result.resolve(true); },
    error: (error) => result.reject(error)
});
```

Web API

```
[ActionName("DeleteMaterials")]
[HttpPost]        
public void DeleteMaterials(JObject jsonData)
{
   dynamic json = jsonData;
   string aa= json.aa;
   string bb= json.bb;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "api/Breeze/DeleteMaterials",
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({ aa: 'aa', bb: 'bb' }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    traditional: true,
    success: () => { result.resolve(true); },
    error: (error) => result.reject(error)
});
```

webAPI:

```
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string Aa { get; set; }
        public string Bb { get; set; }
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public void DeleteMaterials(MyViewModel model) 
    {
        // doing some stuffs here
    }
```